# How do I style one of the parameters in a circle inside an SVG?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a SVG with circles inside it. And I want them to be increasing and decreasing in radius for ever (like a pulsating circle).

My problem is, can I do it with `@keyframes`? Or do I need jquery? And if so, how?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="mapa">
    <svg (svg code here......)
        <circle opacity="0.3" cx="842" cy="451.814" r="25.582" id="1"/>
        <circle opacity="0.3" cx="542" cy="405.814" r="25.582" id="1"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

How do I style the 'r' parameter?

I read I cannot style the 'r' parameter, but this worked:

```
<circle cx="168" cy="179" r="59"
        fill="white" stroke="black"
        onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('r', '72');"
        onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('r', '59');"
/>
```

However, I want to do it with continuous increase and decrease in radius? And not on `mouseover`/`mouseleave`. Something like (r=25, then r=30, then back to 25, and goes on forever). How do I do this?

Thanks for your time, if you can give me any tips I'd apreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use svg smil animate

```html
<svg width="150" height="150">

  <circle opacity="0.3" cx="84%" cy="45%" r="3" id="1">
    <animate attributeName="r" values="3; 10; 3" keyTimes="0; 0.5; 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  
  <circle opacity="0.3" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="10" id="2">
    <animate attributeName="r" values="10; 3; 10" keyTimes="0; 0.5; 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>

</svg>
```

Comment: ty! this worked! perfect man! ty! I just have to edit to fit my design but it's good!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution in CSS with a little hack around SVG containers. You change the container, not the svg. The `circle` element just fills 100% of the container. And the container artificially makes a circle with a `border-radius`.

```css
svg {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 1s;
}
svg:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="100%"
  fill="green" />
</svg>
```

You can figure out how to implement your own keyframes, if this solution works for you.

And just to be clear, JQuery is a framework. You shouldn't bring up JQuery unless this question is *about* JQuery's framework. The language you're looking for is "Javascript" and it's in all major browsers by default. You can use Javascript to do this.

```js
const grow = function(radius) {
  var circle = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0];
  circle.setAttribute('r', radius);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  grow(100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    grow(40);
  }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

```css
circle {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40"
  fill="green" />
</svg>
```